# OLEDB write space into excel

Tags: excel, automation, oledb

I'm using OLEDB to write strings into excel file. It works ok apart from sometimes the space at the begin/end of text is missing for some reason. Things like "abc " or "abc \r\n" became "abc". I notice this by open the generated file in microsoft excel, where I cannot see the space. And when I use the OLEDB to read the generated file back, I cannot see the space as well.
Update:
After some testing, I found that it is not because of the OLEDB. After generating the excel file by OLEDB, I use a little bit excel automation to format the file. The thing I did is very   simple, just changed the width of 2 columns and this bit of code somehow removed the space. Any suggestion is appreciated.

```
            excel = new Excel.Application();
            excel.Workbooks.Open(file, 0, false, 5, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true);
            excel.Visible = false;
            foreach (var obj in excel.Workbooks[1].Worksheets)
            {
                Excel.Worksheet sheet = (Excel.Worksheet)obj;
                sheet.Columns["B"].ColumnWidth = 50;
                sheet.Columns["C"].ColumnWidth = 120;
            }

            excel.Workbooks[1].SaveAs(file, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook,
                missing, missing, missing, missing,
                Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
                missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);
```

update: It seems this is purely a problem of excel, removing the automation code will generate the excel file the same as my expectation. But open/save without any change inside MS excel will remove the leading/trailing space.